# Mobile dropdown nav overlapping content

Tags: css, mobile, drop-down-menu, nav

For my [portfolio site](http://mtthwbsh.com) I'm using a collapsable nav for mobile that opens on toggle. When toggled open, the list items overlaps content whereas I'd like it to push the content down. I don't have any absolute positions or anything so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got "position: relative;" on your NAV element, which is a child of a DIV with an explicitly set height. Removing this height allows your page content to shift down.

Comment: Ah, this was being appended with the jQuery I used. Added height: auto !important; to that element and it seemed to work fine (although it still overlaps content when you scroll to it).